# IE9 lost controlling on child window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, popupwindow

I have some javascipt that open 2 pop up windows with the similar code:

```
Child[i] = window.open(...);
```

And then I try to close all of them from Main window with the following code:

```
setTimeout(Child[i].close(), 5000);
```

The problem is in IE9, the 2 pop up can't be closed, it seem like the main window totally lost control on 2 pop up (child window), but this only happen when 2 URL is real URL, I mean the URL target to a real website (e.g. google.com), on the other hand if the URL is  `about:blank`, so the pop up are closed after 5 secs (which work as expect).

In Chrome, the script work great no matter what is the URL.
I have no idea what is this behaviour of IE, so hope to receive some help from you.
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like security issue, protecting the user from script closing external websites. Anyhow, try adding name to the window when opening it e.g. `Child[i] = window.open("http://www.google.com", "myWindowName");`

Comment: @shadow-wizard thank you but actually i inlcude the name in the script, sorry for didn't show it in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this before closing:

```
Child[i].opener = window;
Child[i].close();
```

Note: This works in IE < 9, haven't tried on 9 yet.

Another thing I just noticed, change your `setTimeout` call to this and try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   Child[i].opener = window;
    Child[i].close();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: thank you but the script seem broke out and nothing happen then